# Getting a null exception while trying to hide the text block in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, null, visibility

I am trying to develop some tools as I am new to WPF. I have a combobox which has 2 items.

the xaml code is as below

```
<Window x:Class="New_generator2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Grid>

        <ComboBox Height="21" Margin="36,15,22,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="True" Text="" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="1" IsSelected="True" Name="ComboBox_Rule_Parameter">Rule_Parameter</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Tag="2" Name="ComboBox_Rule_Instance">Rule_Instance</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>

        <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,71,14,0" Name="Field_Code_textbox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220"  Visibility="Hidden" />
        <TextBlock Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,73,0,0"  Name="Field_Code" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" TextBlock.FontSize="20" Background="BurlyWood" TextAlignment="Center"  Text="Data_Field_Code" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <TextBox Height="84" Margin="35,0,23,12" Name="Script" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="420" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Button Height="25" Margin="120,0,123,106" Name="Generate" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextBlock.FontSize="18" Background="BlanchedAlmond" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Justify" Click="button1_Click" Visibility="Hidden">Dispaly</Button>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And C# code is as below

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Field_Code = new TextBlock();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                Field_Code.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                Field_Code.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Script.Text = Field_Code_textbox.Text;
        }
    }
```

When I run this,  I am getting a Null Exception i.e Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I have attached the screenshot of the null exception.

[image]

please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Try removing "Field_Code = new TextBlock()" Field_code should be created when InitializeComponent is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your initialisation of Field_Code to BEFORE InitialiseComponent() in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because combobox_selection changed is called from InitializeComponent() and at this time your Field_Code is uninitialized. Simpliest workaround is to move `Field_Code = new TextBlock();` before `InitializeComponent();` in Window1() constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like combo selection changed is triggered from InitializeComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would make a property like `public bool FieldCodeVisible { .. }` and bind the visibility of your textbox to that property.

Instead of saying `Field_Code.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` you can say `FieldCodeVisible = true;`

This way you have your **logic in your ViewModel**, but you can decide the on **functionality in your view**.